# Cocoapods error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift2

First time using cocoa pods (latest version) for dependencies in the latest Xcode 7.2.1 with Swift 2.1. I initialize my project folder and then edit the podfile and add my dependencies.  When I run `pod install` it runs without a hitch until I open my project and try to build. I've tried this with two separate projects (one being brand new for testing) and I get `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` for both.  My pod file looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0' #8.0 is minimum supported, right?
use_frameworks!

target 'Testing Frameworks' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
end
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Close your current project and open the .xcworkspace created in your project folder.

Good luck!

Comment: I completely removed all the pod files and dependencies from the project and got a successful build with just the base project files.  Then I did a `pod init` on the project again, added the dependencies to my pod file, did a `pod install` and opened the project with the new `xcworkspace`.  It loads the project but has the exact same error, and a new warning that says: Target 'Pods-project' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'Pods_project.framework' because its architectures 'x86_64' didn't contain all required architectures 'i386 x86_64'

Comment: Got it, I had to change `BUILD ACTIVE ARCHITECTURE ONLY` to NO in the build settings.  Thank you!

Comment: this has been bothering me for a while and I laughed when I read your answer because of how short and simple it was. I wasn't expecting it XD. Thanks for the good work!

Answer (score 14):

First try to **Show the Report navigator** *(8. tab in left navigator of Xcode)* and check the **report**. It should give you some info what is going on like:

`framework not found Pods_[PODFILE_OLD_ABSTRACT_TARGET_NAME]`.

Often when you change the `abstract_target`'s name *(or whatever the Cocoapods is using to name the framework in the future)* in `podfile`, check your target's **Link binary With libraries** under the **Build phases**.

If it keeps the framework with the old name that no longer exists *(next to the new one)*, **remove it**.

Comment: You are my hero.

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to Project Settings.
2. Go to Build Settings.
3. Change BUILD ACTIVE ARCHITECTURE ONLY to NO.

Comment: Godsend...had different values for build / release

Answer (score 6):

I just had similar problem in my project. I found that in GENERAL settings of the project in section "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" there are two files for pods: `"libPods.a"` and `"Pods_ProjectName.framework`"

Deleting `"libPods.a"` helped in my case.

[image: Linked Frameworks and Libraries]

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Pods project
2. Select pod that is throwing an error in targets
3. Go to **iOS Deployment Target**
4. Make sure it matches your project iOS version

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me was adding `$(inherited) flag to LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS in target build settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter this error while developing a pod, it's possible that your module doesn't  export anything.  Check the pattern for `s.source_files` in your `.podspec`.  For me, the glob pattern was missing my source files.